# celery & Amazon ec2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, celery

How do you set up celery (and rabbit) so that they can communicate over an EC2 instance?

Rabbit is running on the instance, on user rabbitmq. I need to send messages to the instance from other computers off the instance, in this case I'm testing with computer.

I've configured celery to work on my computer with a local installation of rabbit.

Furthermore, I've followed these settings to generate the incantation:

http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/configuration.html#broker-settings

This is a redhat instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that rabbit was not accepting messages on the EC2 instance.

To find out if this your error, view the logs after you start / restart rabbit at rabbit@rabbit.log (located at /var/log/rabbbitmq), and you should see an error something like:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 18-Jun-2012::21:41:05 ===
Disk free space limit now exceeded. Free bytes:5404372992 Limit:7836254208
```

To correct this, you need to change the value in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config to:

```
[{rabbit, [{disk_free_limit, {mem_relative, 0.5}}]}].
```

Note that the period is important at the end.

The actual value of mem_relative you will need to adjust based on your needs and how much memory you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your EC2 Security Group rules include the right ports, eg:

22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0
5672    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
11211   tcp 0.0.0.0/0
55672   tcp 0.0.0.0/0